# How to detect Daylight Saving transition in android

Tags: android, timezone, detect

I need to intercept the event that occurs at the daylight saving time change. I thought using a BroadcastReceiver with filter on TIMEZONE_CHANGED. Everything works if the user change time zone, the event is fired and recevied by app, but if I try to simulate the change of daylight saving time, the event is not triggered or received (I don't know) even if the device executes it correctly changing timezone and time.

I've already tried to include the TIME_SET action in intent-filter of manifest receiver with same result.

Here my manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".myReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here my Receiver

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String CLASS_TAG = "myReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.i(CLASS_TAG, action);

    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that “time zone changed” would happen when the time zone is changed, for example from Europe/Rome to Europe/Athens. And that “time set” is when the internal system clock is set, which doesn’t happen at summer time transistions (only the display changes). I don’t know Android, so can’t tell you what you need instead.